# Prawn::Errors::IncompatibleStringEncoding: When working with Turkish characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I get the following error when I try to to make prawn print the following characters - `Eylül Çamcı`

```
Prawn::Errors::IncompatibleStringEncoding: 
Your document includes text that's not compatible with the Windows-1252 character set.
```

My code for this is -

```
cell_4 = pdf.make_cell(content: "Eylül Çamcı", font: "app/pdfs/fonts/opensans.ttf")
```

Prawn Documentation recommends to use a TTF font, but I have already done that and can confirm that open source supports these characters.

What can I do now?

Comment: Try this `"Eylül Çamcı".force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')`